# Как перейти на action контроллера?

Tags: php, magento

Есть контроллер `customer` в нем `action` - `add` (Magento1)

как с кнопки в  `phtml` перейти на этот `action`?

Делаю так:

```
<form action="<?php Mage::getUrl('*/customer/add')?>">
<button class="add_product_button button" type="submit">add product</button>
</form>
```

Страница грузится но остается так как была!

Comment: А что в action? Полностью путь укажите с именем модуля, например `mycustome/customer/add`

Comment: @Naumov, указывал) тот же результат

Comment: Код экшена, может он у вас рендерит это же представление, и получившийся url тоже покажите?

Comment: @Naumov, заменил  `action="<?php Mage::getUrl('*/customer/add')?>"` на `action="<?php   echo Mage::getUrl('*/customer/add')?>"`  и заработало )

Comment: Да это частая ошибка даже я `echo` иной раз забываю вставить :D

Comment: @Naumov, 90%  проблем у меня из за этого!

Comment: У меня меньше проблем из за этого но процентов 5 да будет я бэкэндер, так что в шаблоны сильно не лезу, там другие люди работают.

Comment: @Naumov, спасибо за отклик ))